# How can I cancel action made by GoogleAuthUtil#requestGoogleAccountsAccess()?

Tags: android-8.0-oreo, accountmanager

Starting with Android O, `AccountManager#getAccounts()` won't work even GET_ACCOUNTS permission is granted. One way to access accounts is to use    `newChooseAccountIntent()` to let user pick account. But it makes UI very poor.

2nd option I found is to use `GoogleAuthUtil#requestGoogleAccountsAccess()` and let the user give the access right to Google accounts to my app. After successfully getting rights for that, my app could work just like before in Android O. So it looks like another run time permission.

But here comes the big issue: I can't cancel (reverse) action made by `GoogleAuthUtil#requestGoogleAccountsAccess()`. I thought uninstalling my app does that like runtime permission but it won't. So now I can't test flow again since `GoogleAuthUtil#requestGoogleAccountsAccess()` simply returns true and I have no way to open up a dialog to ask user to grant access to accounts.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in the Google Support site. You can follow the below steps to remove access.

**Remove site or app access**

If you gave account access to a site or app you no longer trust, you can remove its access to your Google Account. The site or app won’t be able to access any more info from your Google Account, but you may need to request that they delete the data they already have.

1. Go to your Google Account.
2. On the left navigation panel, select Security.
3. On the Third-party apps with account access panel, select Manage
   third-party access.
4. Select the site or app you want to remove.
5. Select Remove Access.

Source : https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en

Comment: This is not an answer to my question.

Comment: Oh, for 2nd option I have answered. Did you try it? If you want to ask for account selection every time, you can use **newChooseAccountIntent** (Account selectedAccount, ArrayList<Account> allowableAccounts, String[] allowableAccountTypes, **boolean alwaysPromptForAccount**, String descriptionOverrideText, String addAccountAuthTokenType, String[] addAccountRequiredFeatures, Bundle addAccountOptions) with alwaysPromptForAccount as true @Tomcat